# Adding Group Average Line to Bar Chart

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a PivotChart in the form of a bar chart and I would like to add a group average line on the chart.

I have this (sample) table in my PowerPivot Data Model:

[image: Table1]

Group averages are A: 20, B: 50 and C: 80. My bar chart looks like this.
[image: Bar chart]

How would I do this? Do I need to add a measure? If so, how? I am not that great with DAX functions yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not sure this is what you are looking for, here is what I think you are asking.

First, you are going to need an additional column. Two ways to get er done.

1. **Calculated column**

   =CALCULATE (
   AVERAGE ( Range[Value] ),
   FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Range ), Range[Group] = EARLIER ( Range[Group] ) )
   )
2. **Measure**

   =CALCULATE (
   AVERAGE ( Range[Value] ),
   FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Range ), Range[Group] = MAX( Range[Group] ) )
   )

Now edit your pivot table:

[image: Pivot table fileds set up]

Now select your chart type:

[image: change chart type image]

For future reference you should look into [Power BI.  It has features which do these sorts of calculations automatically](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-quick-measures).

If your looking for something different it would help is you provided the expected outcome.